# Lock filtered tasks in MS Project 2003

Tags: vba, ms-project

In MS Project 2003, I need to apply some filters to a schedule, so that only some tasks are shown. This is easy and I know how to do it, but when I change the view, the filter vanishes, and i need to apply it again. Is there any way I can lock the filtered tasks so that when I change the view, the filter maintains itself? Can be through vba also.

Answer (score 0):

Views are a collection of settings: the table definition, group, and filter. So by definition, the filter will be reset when you select another view. One suggestion would be to create the set of views that you need and have them all use your desired filter.

You could create a macro and attach it to a button, but it would be almost as easy to re-select the filter as it would be to click the button to run the macro.

Comment: Thank you. How to create that "set of views that I need and have them all use my desired filter"? Is there any way to attach a filter to a view or set of views?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick exemple of how to use filters in MSProject VBA. This filters by Unique ID:

```
Sub Filter_unique_ID()

Dim R As Resource
Dim Report_End As String

ViewApply Name:="Detail Gantt"
'TableApply Name:="Task Tracking"
Report_End = InputBox$("Enter the unique ID:")
If Report_End <> "" Then
FilterEdit Name:="Select", Taskfilter:=True, Create:=True, _
OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Unique ID", Test:="equals", _
Value:=Report_End, ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False

FilterApply Name:="Select"
End If
End Sub
```

This function clears all filters:

```
Sub ClearFilters()
FilterClear
End Sub
```